# (Java) How do I make switch if one of the case contains <,>,<=, or >=

Tags: java

For example, I want to have it like

```
switch (var){
    case <10:
        System.out.println("var is lower than 10!");
}
```

If there is already a similar question that is answered, can I please have the link, thanks!

Comment: you don't, you would use an if-else if structure. either that, or the waterfall principle, but if it 's about large values, I would strongly recommend against

Comment: `switch` statement is not the right tool for this kind of comparison; use `if-else` statement

Comment: This question was closed but a link to a question about JavaSCRIPT was added? It's completely unrelated.

Comment: The Java Language Specification for [Java 11](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11) and for [Java 17](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11) in the end both state that a SwitchLabel must be either a constant expression or the name of an enum constant. `<10` is not a neither and therefore not allowed by Java.